# Loading model/service contents before table is shown on the screen

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have some complex problem in which I am supposed to get data from a service before my screen gets loaded.
I am using ODataModel in the application. What I want is, I want to populate data from a service and show it in another table in one of the columns while other columns of the table should have data from my static json.

I was trying to create one table and tie it with the data from the service we want but setting the table to invisible as I don't want to make use of this table. The purpose of creating this table is to have data from the service loaded and the purpose of setting it to invisible is not to show users the things of no use. But I got to know that, unless and until the table is rendered on the screen, we don't get the data from the model.

How can this be achieved? Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure? The data retrieval is asynchronous indeed (but you could make it synchronous), but nothing stops you from retrieving the data and *not* bind it to a table

Comment: Yes, I am quite sure. Can you please give me some example if it's not the case? That will be a great help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're misinformed ;-) See answer below

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example : http://jsbin.com/qilaf/2/edit?js,console,output

I have used a local JSON model instead of an OData model, but if you look at the console, it perfectly shows the program flow (and that the model is loaded prior to the table rendering):

1. controller.loadData() - data is loaded
2. view.createContent() - table is created (not yet rendered)
3. controller.onInit() - table now rendered
4. view.onAfterRendering() - everything is now rendered

On a sidenote, I would not advice loading a model from the view, but that's a matter of style/taste, this example was merely intended to show the creation/loading of a model is totally independent from the creation/rendering of UI controls